# newline is missing after the result of "\n".join(list) inserted into cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I am using `beautifulsoup` and `openpyxl` to get some web links;

My code is;

1. Use `beautifulsoup` to get the `href` of a tag, and append them to a list
2. use `join` to concatenate the multiple web links of the list to a string joining with `"\n"`
3. insert that concatenated string to a cell

I am confused, don't know what happened.

Here is a reproducible example,

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("c:\\python\\test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
detail = ['pic','movie name','page link','release date','下download link','detail']
detail_str="\n".join(detail)
ws.cell(1,1,detail_str)
wb.save("c:\\python\\test.xlsx")
wb.close
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure your question has a [mre].

Comment: From the sound of the title, you need to add a newline at the end of `detail_str`. So change your declaration to `detail_str="\n".join(detail) + "\n"`. What `.join()` does is puts the string **between** elements, so its missing the string before or after the list.

Comment: Using `wb.close` in your code does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code **does exactly** what it would be expected to do.
You are not clear on what exactly the issue is however it may simply be a `display issue`.

`detail_str` is a string with words separated by line feeds written to a single cell.
The result is cell `'A1'` with a string which on opening may look like the linespaces are not included as shown in this screenshot below;
[image]

However you can see in the formula bar that only 'pic' is visible because the rest of the string is below that first word due to the first `line feed` inserted after 'pic'.
The cell row height and/or formula bar needs to be expanded to see the line feeds in effect like the screenshot below.

[image]

You can set the row height with Openpyxl using the height param like

```
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 90
```

to fit the string vertically in the cell 
**but note**, due to the nature of Openpyxl even though the row height is expanded to fit all the words you will still see the string as a single line after opening the sheet. You would need to refresh the cell to have it re-organise to display as shown in screenshot 2, (then save the workbook to update). Refresh the cell by selecting cell 'A1' then 'F2' (edit cell) then return. Expanding the formula bar is done manually.

Comment: Thanks, but how to refresh the cell in the code ?

Comment: You cannot with Openpyxl as it does not use Excel. To have the cell refresh you would need to have a macro run when the sheet is opened or perhaps use another module.